# Не рабоатет приложение на ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Хочу изучить React.JS. Работаю под линуксом. Установил реакт командами `npm install react` и `npm install react-dom`. Куда произошла установка и откуда в проектах будут подключаться модули - не понял.

Написал такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>React App</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

`script.js`:

```
import react from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Однако при открытии index.html в браузере ничего не произошло. Что я сделал не так? Как правильно подключить и использовать реакт? Каким образом библиотеки реакта линкуются с проектом?

Comment: зависимости устанавливаются в папку node_modules

Comment: можете показать ваше дерево проекта? ошибок никаких нет в консоли?

Answer (score -1):

Просто используй в **нужной** директории команду.

Т.е., если ты хочешь создать проект в директории **X**, то используя `cd` в терминале, перейди в директорию **X**.

А уже там:

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-react-beginners-guide/).